# Printing particular row from table in html

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a table , where list of transactions displayed , now I want to print particular row alone for that I used `printToCart` function and passed the items in that row, and data also passing and assigned to `$scope.printValues`, But that values are not passing in my html , I mean couldnt viewed in html.

JS:

```
 $scope.printToCart = function(printSectionId,item) {
        $scope.printValues = item;
    var innerContents = document.getElementById(printSectionId).innerHTML;

      var popupWindow =  window.open('', '_blank', 'width=900,height=800,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
    popupWindow.document.open();
       $scope.datagetinLoading = false; $('#preparingToSaveInvoice').modal('hide'); 
$('#preparingToPrintInvoice').modal('hide');
$('#preparingToDownloadPDF').modal('hide');
        $('#printReceiptDetailsWaiting').modal('hide');
    popupWindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic"><body onload="window.print()"><style>#footer { position:relative;  bottom:0; width:100%; height: auto; } #header { display: flow-root; height: auto; border-bottom: 1px solid #333;} </style><div class="wrapper" style="padding-right: 10px;">' + innerContents + '</div></body></html>');

    popupWindow.document.close();  


  };
```

Print HTML :

```
    <div id="printquotationPreview" hidden>
      <div>
    <table class="table table-responsive"
      <tbody>
 <tr><td><div><img src="assets/img/logo.png">
 <p> INVOICE</p> </div></td></tr>

                       </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
              <br>
            <div class="row col-sm-12">
                <div>

   <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>SL.NO</th>  
            <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th>AMOUNT</th>

                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr class="table-row">
                            <td >1</td>

            <td>Credit Purchase {{printValues.credits}}</td>
            <td>{{printValues.cost}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>    

      </div>
```

Comment: Is this your mobile app or browser web app?

Comment: this is browser app